# Не срабатывает header()

Tags: php

Залил сайт на хостинг, и сразу же столкнулся с такой проблемой, как нерабочий header(), хотя на локальном сервере он работал исправно. Если я не ошибаюсь, то синтаксис правильный. страница на которую я хочу перейти находится в той же директории.

```
            <?php
                if ( !empty($pwd) && !empty($email) ) {
                    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email = :email'); //Добавили id, для перенаправления на личную страницу
                    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
                    $stmt->execute();
            
                    $user_p = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            
                    if ($user_p){
                        if(password_verify($pwd, $user_p->password)){
                            $_SESSION['id'] = $user_p->id;
                            header('Location: office.php?id='. $_SESSION['id']);
                            //$office = "office.php?id=". $_SESSION['id'];
                            //header('Location: $office');
                        }else{
                            echo '<p class="wrong">Неверный Email или пароль</br>Если Вы не зарегестрированы</p>';
                            echo '<a href="registration.php" class="reg">Зарегестрироваться</a>';
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo '<p class="wrong">Неверный Email или пароль</br>Если Вы не зарегестрированы</p>';
                        echo '<a href="registration.php">Зарегестрироваться</a>';
                    }
                }else{
                    echo '<p class="noValues">Пожалуйста, заполните все поля</p>';
                }                
        ?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста решение проблемы. Уже второй вечер сижу.

**UPD**

Если прописываю так:

```
header('Location: /index.html');
```

Всё равно не срабатывает.

Comment: Ошибка какая-то есть?

Comment: При редиректе укажите полный урл т.е `//domain.ru/office.php?id='. $_SESSION['id']`

Comment: Перед `<?php` не должно быть никаких символов (в том числе отступов). т.к. это идет сразу на вывод на страницу. `header()` должен использозваться до любого вывода.

Comment: @Dmitriy к сожалению нету ошибок. А Нотайсы я отключил.

Comment: @Arsen не помогает.

Comment: @Knyaz71 отступы убрал, выводы не используются до header().

Comment: @Dmitriy у меня когда открывается страница входа, сразу выводиться эта часть
else{
                    echo '<p class="noValues">Пожалуйста, заполните все поля</p>';
                }                
        ?>
Я ввожу правильные данные для входа, и она пропадает, и я так же остаюсь на странице входа. Без ошибок и так далее.

Comment: @Knyaz71 Ваш ответ оказался верным. Спасибо.